# Generating values of x,y for equally spaced x in an interval

Tags: r

I am new to working in R and I would like to generate values of x,y to plot for lowess smoothing. I would like to generate equally spaced x values in an interval for a given function.

For example, I would like to generate the values for the function:

```
f(x) = 5x^3 - 2x^2 -2x +1
```

in the interval of [-5,5].

(p.s. my background is in biology so I don't understand the technical things as well as I would like!)

Comment: And you are working with integers in that interval? This may be as simple as `f1 <- function(x) (5*x)^3 - (2*x)^2 - 2*x + 1; f1(seq(-5,5))`

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this

```
f1 <- function(x) (5*x)^3 - (2*x)^2 - 2*x + 1
seqx <- seq(-5,5, by = 0.1)
plot(seqx, f1(seqx), pch = 20)
```

[image]